# Problema al agregar una carpeta local a un repositorio en Github

Tags: github

trate de agregar una carpeta local a un repositorio ya creado en github sin embargo, cuando escribo el comando 'git add . ' o 'git add nombre-carpeta'
me sale el siguiente mensaje

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
modified:   h-2 (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: como estas agregando la carpeta?, mediante GUI, o CLI, explica mejor como estas realizando las acciones

Comment: estoy agregandola desde VSCODE con los comandos de github @David081

Answer (score 0):

ese error sale porque tienes cambios que no han sido agregados al `commit`, tienes que agregar todos los cambios  para que luego hagas un push a tu repositorio remoto
podrias probar con los siguientes comandos:

```
git add .
git commit -m "agregando cambios que no estaban antes"
git push nombreDeTuRepoRemoto nombreDeTuRama
```

Comment: me dice esto: fatal: 'nombre del repositorio' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: En nombre del repositorio debes poner el nombre de tu repositorio remoto, desconozco cual es el nombre que tiene eso debes saberlo tu, al igual que el nombre de la rama.

Comment: no de todas maneras no me sirvio